# Why has my account been blocked for asking questions that are very valuable to a new developer?

Tags: support, post-ban

My account on Stack Overflow has been blocked for asking questions that are valuable for a new developer.

But I don't know why my account was blocked: I can understand a downvote for a question, but not blocking my account.

Please help me to unblock this account.

Comment: There is a link in block message. Did you not follow it and read it? If you did, what did you not understand there?

Comment: I want my account back how can you block my account like this

Comment: Last time. Read the article. It explains.

Comment: Free site, yes. Free ride, no.

Comment: @mubu I write this comment with absolutely no care. If I can't ask any questions, it really makes no sense. Some of these nerds on stack overflow, this is their only source of power. In real life they are just insecure loosers behind a keyboard. I can say I never asked a dumb question or tried to waste anybody's time. And I have spent my time answering questions. I only asked questions when I am stuck and google nor MSDN is helping. But no problem. I will soon host my own question and answers site.

Comment: And this site is extremely unfair. The last time I deleted my account, because someone was downvoting my answer where I showed how you can change the address a reference is pointing in C++. Even though I deleted my accounted, stack overflow still kept all those beautiful answers I had wrote.

Answer (score 40):

Those are low quality questions. Apart from your complete lack of use of paragraphs (which makes it very difficult to read your questions), they don't show any research or effort.

The block has nothing to do with being a new developer and everything to do with the quality of the questions - our [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) has resources about asking good questions. The questions you have posted fall very short.

After a few of those (and after showing you a warning), you have not cleaned up your act. So the account got blocked.

To lift the block, follow the instructions in article linked from the block message.